# data visualization plots according to contexts

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

can you please check if my plot ideas are correct for context:

0. a series of 10 individuals described by continuous variable/a series of 200 individuals described by a continuous variable frequency distribution of a categorical variable with 10 categories: Histogram
1. a series of 300 individuals described by continuous variable and a categorical variable with 5 categories: swarm or beeswarm
2. a series of 200 individuals described by a numerical discrete variable with 5 modalities: barchart
3. a series of 200 individuals described by continuous variable and a categorical variable with 4 categories/a series of 200 individuals described by continuous variable and a categorical variable with 4 categories: box plot(edited)
4. a contingency table with two categorical variables with 10 categories and 3 categories/a contingency table with a numerical discrete variable and a categorical variable with 3 categories: stacked percentage bar chart

Comment: 1. is appropriate; all others are inappropriate or could be improved. Is this homework?

Comment: @jared_mamrot does this look like home work?! I am a coder who is transitioning to data analytics. Can you elaborate please how they can be improved or what is the inappropriate?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the type of question I would include in an intro stats course - "which is the most appropriate visualisation method for xx?". My apologies if that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to plot your data. Here are some suggestions with examples:

Series of 10 individuals continuous variable:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
data("mtcars")
mtcars %>%
  sample_n(size = 10) %>% 
  select(disp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = disp,
             x = "Type of car",
             label = rownames(.),
             color = rownames(.))) +
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text_repel(nudge_x = -.5) +
  ylab("Displacement") +
  ggtitle("Cars (from 'mtcars')") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_1.png]

Series of 200 individuals described by a continuous variable:

```
library(titanic)
library(ggbeeswarm)
data("Titanic")
titanic_train %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  sample_n(200) %>% 
  select(Age) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Age,
             x = "Age of passangers")) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_quasirandom(groupOnX = TRUE,
                   size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Passengers (from 'titanic')") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_2.png]

Frequency distribution of a categorical variable with 10 categories:

```
data("cars")
cars %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(Average_speed = factor(speed)) %>% 
  count(Average_speed, name = "frequency") %>%
  sample_n(10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Average_speed,
             y = frequency)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Average Speed (from 'cars')") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_3.png]

A series of 300 individuals described by continuous variable and a categorical variable with 5 categories:

```
data("Titanic")
titanic_train %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  sample_n(300) %>% 
  select(Fare, Survived) %>% 
  mutate(Survived = factor(Survived,
                           labels = c("Died",
                                      "Lived"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Fare,
             x = Survived,
             group = Survived)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_quasirandom(groupOnX = TRUE,
                   size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Passengers (from 'titanic')") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format()) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_4.png]
Series of 200 individuals described by a numerical discrete variable with 5 modalities:

```
data("Titanic")
titanic_train %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  sample_n(200) %>%
  select(Parch) %>% 
  filter(Parch < 5) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Parch)) +
  geom_bar() +
  ggtitle("Passengers (from 'titanic')") +
  ylab("Number of Parents/Children Aboard") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_5.png]

Series of 200 individuals described by continuous variable and a categorical variable with 4 categories:

```
titanic_train %>%
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(Survived = factor(Survived,
                           labels = c("Died",
                                      "Lived"))) %>%  
  mutate(Interaction = interaction(Survived, Sex)) %>% 
  select(Interaction, Age) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Age,
             x = Interaction)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_quasirandom(aes(color = Interaction),
                   size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Passengers (from 'titanic')") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example_6.png]

A contingency table with two categorical variables with 10 categories and 3 categories:

```
library(janitor)
library(ggpubr)
library(palmerpenguins)
part_1 <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(species, flipper_length_mm) %>% 
  mutate(freq_table = cut(flipper_length_mm, breaks = 10)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = species, x = freq_table, fill = flipper_length_mm)) +
  geom_tile() +
  ggtitle("'Palmer's Penguins' dataset") +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Flipper length (mm)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

part_2 <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(species, flipper_length_mm) %>% 
  mutate(freq_table = cut(flipper_length_mm, breaks = 10)) %>%
  tabyl(freq_table, species) %>% 
  ggtexttable()

ggarrange(part_1, part_2, ncol = 1)
```

[image: example_7.png]